# Angular-cli is not installed issue even though it is installed

Tags: angular, angular-cli

[image]

Here it is my packages

```
"license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.42",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "angular2-http-file-upload": "^1.0.6",
    "angular2-qrcode": "^2.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.3.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^1.5.2",
    "ng2-datetime": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.1",
    "ng2-qrcode-reader": "0.0.1",
    "ng2-webcam": "^1.2.4",
    "ngx-qrcode2": "0.0.3",
    "require": "^2.4.20",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "traceur": "0.0.111",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.3.2"
  }
```

UPDATE: I've installed python and node-gyp  and shows this

see screen shot I used 2 commands the other one doesnt work

Comment: Look like require python 2. Did you install it?

Comment: With which command did you try to install angular-cli?

Comment: No I'll try to install it

Comment: you need python >2.5.0 & <3.0.0, you have installed 3.6.1 which is causing the issue

Comment: @echonax npm install --save-dev -g @angular/cli@latest

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Python executable is v3.6.1, which is not supported by gyp

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) of the node-gyp python v2.7 recommended and v3.x.x is not supported. Just try install python version 2.7 and then install gyp (see [installation guide](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation) on the github page).

Or maybe this command would help you too
`npm install --python=python2.7`

Then `npm install -g node-gyp`

Comment: C:\Users\sec_m\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- @angular/cli@1.2.3

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Comment: Did not understand all problem. Need more information. According to you update try `npm install --save @angular/compiler-cli` or just read this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5654) on the github

Comment: Do you have latest version of node installed on your system?

and have you installed angular cli globally?